# file downloaded via firefox and curl have different size

Tags: firefox, download, http, curl, headers

When I download a file from this [link](http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0) by `Firefox` its size is `74580 B`, But when I download it by `curl` with exactly all of header was sent by `Firefox` its size is `79891 B` (I copied all header from `Firefox` and paste it in `curl` command).
what is the problem?

If you need any additional data ask me in comment.

My curl command:

```
curl --header 'Host: members.tsetmc.com' --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0' --header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' --header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --header 'Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F' --header 'Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=pwzbckbdpjlzqj45vcdbd455' --header 'Connection: keep-alive' 'http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0' -o 'MarketWatchPlus-1393_3_14.xlsx' -L
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Webserver` that is serve that file has enabled `gzip` compression, `Firefox` uncompress the gzip, but for curl I should `--compressed` to uncompress it.

So my curl command is:

```
curl --header 'Host: members.tsetmc.com' --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0' --header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' --header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --header 'Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F' --header 'Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=pwzbckbdpjlzqj45vcdbd455' --header 'Connection: keep-alive' 'http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0' -o 'MarketWatchPlus-1393_3_14.xlsx' -L --compressed
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad you sorted it. I find **meld** on Ubuntu incredibly useful for comparing text files: it installs compare options into the Nautilus file manager context menu:-

- if two or more files are selected, the context option is **Compare**, and **meld** is scheduled to compare all of them (I don't recommend more than four);
- if a single file is selected, the context option is **Compare Later**, and the next file selected has the context menu **Compare to** *previous file*, as well as **Compare Later** to make this the new reference file for the next selection (for use if the files are on different discs or in different directories).

Comment: I have meld, But I think meld doesn't work for binary files. am I true?

Comment: You are correct that **meld** doesn't work for binary files (it is a pity that it doesn't at least flag if two binary files are identical or not), but web sites are HTML text files, and **meld** works well on them.

In your case it would show the uncompressed file as text and the other as binary, so you would know immediately that there was a significant difference. You can look at binary files with bless.

Comment: If both files are binary, the shell command **cmp** will tell you if they are identical or not, while the **file** command gives a reasonably good indication of the file type.

There are some binary comparison tools which will try to rematch after differences, but I have not tried them, and they would be of little use for compressed files, as small differences in uncompressed files will give huge differences when compressed.

(Sorry, I did not realise that I had been logged out, and I originally added a new answer, because it would not let me add another comment.)